# How can I make an iPhone UITextField required?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How can I make a **UITextField** required? In other words, if the entry is empty, then refocus them on the required field.

Answer (score 2):

Set a delegate for your field, and implement `-textFieldShouldEndEditing:` in it.

Answer (score 1):

check length of textfield by [textfieldname.length] > 0. if it is then move else do textfield became first responder.